# repeating a program in java

Tags: java, repeat

I've been trying to repeat this program, but when I do, I keep getting errors.  I repeated it before, but it asked to repeat after every row of asterisks.  This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Pyramid 
{

//Displaying a Pyramid
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  //Get user input = number of rows to print in a pyramid
  System.out.print("Enter an integer for the number of rows: ");
  int userInput = scanner.nextInt();
  scanner.close();

  int myLevel;
  int i, j , k;

  myLevel = userInput;

  for (i = 1; i <= myLevel; i++) {

  for (k =1; k <= myLevel-i; k++)

  System.out.print(" ");

  for (j = k+1; j <=myLevel; j++) 

  System.out.print( "*");
  for(int l=myLevel;l>k-1;l--)
  System.out.print( "*");

  System.out.println("");
   System.out.println("You want to continue : (Y/N) ");
    } while("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.next().trim()));
  }

}
```

Comment: Can you plz be more clear about what is going on in your code? can you post up your error?

Comment: What errors are you seeing? And what does your question have to do with network programming? This seems about as far removed as any question I've seen here.

Comment: You need to read up on while loops. Please check out the tutorial here: [while loop tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html), and I'll take the liberty of removing the network programming tag as it does nothing but distract. You will want to be very careful to use correct tags so as not to confuse folks who mean to help you. Oops, Don beat me too it.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing that you want to repeat the above logic - right?

If this is the case then do not close your `scanner`

Also your while is wrongly formatted.

```
while("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.next().trim()));
```

Having the `;` on the end will cause an endless loop in this case.

try

```
private static void myMethod(Scanner scanner) {
      //Get user input = number of rows to print in a pyramid
      System.out.print("Enter an integer for the number of rows: ");
      int userInput = scanner.nextInt();

      int myLevel;
      int i, j , k;

      myLevel = userInput;

      for (i = 1; i <= myLevel; i++) {

      for (k =1; k <= myLevel-i; k++)

      System.out.print(" ");

      for (j = k+1; j <=myLevel; j++) 

      System.out.print( "*");
      for(int l=myLevel;l>k-1;l--)
      System.out.print( "*");

      System.out.println("");

}
```

and

call it like

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    do {
        myMethod (scanner);
        System.out.println("You want to continue : (Y/N) ");
    } while("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.next().trim()));   

    scanner.close ();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an empty while statement at the end of code. You're trying to read input that doesn't exist. You need to encapsulate the entire program in a loop. You don't need to loop until there is input.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);



do{
          //Get user input = number of rows to print in a pyramid
          System.out.print("Enter an integer for the number of rows: ");
          int userInput = scanner.nextInt();

          int myLevel;
          int i, j , k;

          myLevel = userInput;

          for (i = 1; i <= myLevel; i++) {

          for (k =1; k <= myLevel-i; k++)

          System.out.print(" ");

          for (j = k+1; j <=myLevel; j++) 

          System.out.print( "*");
          for(int l=myLevel;l>k-1;l--)
          System.out.print( "*");

          System.out.println("");
            } 
          System.out.println("You want to continue : (Y/N) ");
          } while("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.next().trim()));
    }
```

You also close the scanner, so you can't re-use it.