# repeating a program with arrays

Tags: java, arrays, repeat

I'm trying to get my program to repeat, but it's not working out too well.  This is what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;//to use scanner class
public class ArrayDemo
{
public static void main(String args[])
{
   int a[]=new int[5];
   Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);//use to take input
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)//arrayname.length gives the length of array
   {
       System.out.println("Enter number:");
       a[i]=sc.nextInt();
   }

   int sum=0;
   long pro=1;
   int max=a[0];
   int min=a[0];
   for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
   {
       sum=sum+a[i];
       pro=pro*a[i];
       if(a[i]>max)
       max=a[i];
       if(a[i]<min)
       min=a[i];



   }
   float avg=sum/a.length;
   System.out.print("You entered");
   for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
   {
       System.out.print(", 1"+a[i]);

   }

       System.out.println("\nThe sum of those numbers is "+sum);
       System.out.println("The product of those numbers is "+pro);
       System.out.println("The largest number entered is "+max);
       System.out.println("The smallest number entered is "+min);
       System.out.println("The average of the numbers entered is "+avg);

}
}
```

I have another program that I'm trying to work into repeating, but it says no main applets or methods to be found, so it doesn't return anything:

```
import java.util.*;//to use scanner class
public class ArrayDemo
{
public static void myMethod(Scanner scanner)
{

   int a[]=new int[5];
          int i;
   for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)//arrayname.length gives the length of array
   {
       System.out.println("Enter number:");
       a[i]=scanner.nextInt();
   }

   int sum=0;
   long pro=1;
   int max=a[0];
   int min=a[0];
   for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
   {
       sum=sum+a[i];
       pro=pro*a[i];
       if(a[i]>max)
       max=a[i];
       if(a[i]<min)
       min=a[i];


   }
   float avg=sum/a.length;
   System.out.print("You entered");
   for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)
   {
       System.out.print(","+a[i]);

   }

       System.out.println("\nThe sum of those numbers is "+sum);
       System.out.println("The product of those numbers is "+pro);
       System.out.println("The largest number entered is "+max);
       System.out.println("The smallest number entered is "+min);
       System.out.println("The average of the numbers entered is "+avg);

       System.out.println();


do {
    myMethod (scanner);
    System.out.println("You want to continue : (Y/N) ");
} while("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.next().trim()));   

scanner.close ();



}

}
```

Comment: put it in a while loop

Comment: Hi Haley, this looks familiar.  In the code that I gave you before, you need to call it from a main method.

Comment: in your 2nd approach you don't have main method . So file will not get run

Comment: possible duplicate of [repeating a program in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25276548/repeating-a-program-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

You need a main method like

```
public static void main(String args[])

  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

  do {
    myMethod (scanner);
    System.out.println("You want to continue : (Y/N) ");
  } while("Y".equalsIgnoreCase(scanner.next().trim()));   

  scanner.close ();

}
```

so move this code to a main method from your (my) `myMethod

Answer (score 0):

Your first code has main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {// some code }
```

but second code has not this method. In the java language a program must start from main method with above signature.

Answer (score 0):

In your 2nd approach you don't have the main method. So you can't run the file.
Another thing is don't put all the logic in main method. Try your best to separate them as much as possible. Then it is more clear.
Put your calculation logic to a method and call it from a while or do while loop

e.g.

```
class A{
     public static void main(String args[]){
          Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
          int[] a= new int[5];
          boolean bRepeat = true;
          while(bRepeat){
              for(i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                  System.out.println("Enter number:");
                  a[i]=sc.nextInt();
              }
              System.out.println("Sum is " + getSum(a));
              System.out.println("Average is " + getAvergae(a));
              .....
              System.out.println("Do you wanna repeat? T/F");
              String response = scanner.nextLine();
              if(response.equalsIgnoreCase("T"))
                  bRepeat = true;
              else
                  bRepeat = false;                      // or break
          }
     }

     public static int getSum(int[] number){
         //logic
     }
     public static double getAverage(int[] number){
         //logic
     }
     public static int getProduct(int[] number){
         //logic
     }
     public static int getMax(int[] number){
         //logic
     }
     ................
}
```